# C++ preprocessor and overloading issues

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have the following problem:

Let's consider we have

```
#define SET callMe
#define COLUMN(x) #x
```

and in our main block of our program we have the following line:
`SET(COLUMN(price)="hi");` which after the preprocessor running is translated to:

```
#callMe("price"="hi");
```

I need function `callMe` signature to be `callMe(string str)` so that leaves us to have to make something to make the `"price"="hi"` to `"price=hi"` and let `callMe` function to handle the rest of the problem. Last thing to state is that all this program I describe is a part of a Table class.

The only option I have is overload the operator `=` so the `"price"="hi"` translated to the wanted one, but I can't get what I should overload because I first thought that doing the following overload

`#std::string operator=(std::string str)` as a member function of the Table class but it seems I can't get it right on track.

Any clues of how I can achieve the wanted operations?

Comment: Why on earth are you using the preprocessor for this? It would be so much better to just create a set of classes with overloaded operators that built up an SQL expression as an AST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this any good to you?

```
#define SECOND_PASS(x) callMe(#x)
#define COLUMN(x) x
#define SET(x) SECOND_PASS(x)
```

which results in:

```
callMe("price=\"hi\"");
```

This essentially gets the preprocessor to remove COLUMN before converting to a string.

Comment: Seems of doing some great help because it also helps if instead of "hi" we have an integer. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: I was thinking of something like this, but couldn't quite figure out exactly how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

To get what you want, you would have to write your code as `SET(COLUMN(price)"=hi")`.

You can't overload `operator=()` for a built-in type. This is done for sanity maintenance, among other reasons.

C++ overloading is not intended to allow you to force the compiler to parse a different language.

P.S. Overloading `operator=()` in the `Table` class only handles the case where a `Table` is on the left-hand side of the `=`.  That would require `COLUMN(x)` to return a `Table` object, probably not what you want.  You could use an adaptor class to get this effect, but the syntax of `COLUMN(x)` doesn't include which table this column is from, so you're stuck there too.

One *way out there* solution would look something like this:

```
class ColumnSetter
{public:
    ColumnSetter(const char* name): name(name), value(0) {}
    ColumnSetter& operator=(const char* value_) { value = value_; }
    operator std::string const &() const { std::string result(name);
        if(value) { result.append('='); result.append(value); } return result; }
private:
    const char* name;
    const char* value;
};

#define COLUMN(x) ColumnSetter(#x)

void callMe(const std::string& param);
```

Reformat and de-inline to whatever coding standards you have.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Are there any clues if i still want to make that "price"="hi" to be "price=hi" , i can't alter the syntax i can't think of something else :(

Answer (score 0):

You mean like

`#define SET(x) (CallMe(x))`

ps - usual disclaimer about using the preprocessor

Comment: i think the define i state above is still ok executing a           g++ -E main.cpp produces callMe("price"="hi") so i guess defines are ok ! , i am aware about the preprocessor but i must do it that way :( , Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

This should be done with classes that overload the various logical operators to create an abstract syntax tree instead of actually performing the operation. Then you can express various SQL expressions as C++ code and get an abstract syntax tree out which can then be serialized into an SQL `WHERE` clause.

This isn't very hard, and if you are careful about it, it will be pretty efficient. It's much better than trying to use preprocessor hackery to create an SQL expression builder.

Comment: You are right , but we originally organized the solution the preprocessor way , i cant afford the time to alter the original design so i am looking to a solution to the problem i have , that i can't overcome, Thanks a lot for the clue i will definately try it out later on :)